# CSS and modifying div's width if radio button checked

Tags: html, css

JavaScript not accepted this time.

So, I have this CSS code. This code should change to width if radio button is checked. Nothing happens. How could I modify the code?

```
input[type="radio"]#someID-1:checked #extra { width: 4000px; }
```

I also have this HTML code:

```
<div id="kaaviotaulukko" style="white-space: nowrap; position: relative; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK">
      <input id="someID-1" name="nappi" type="radio">
      <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:left;width:0">
        <div id="navi3">
          <div style="z-index:100;position:fixed;right:0;top:300px">
            <span><label for="someID-1">1</label></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kierros" style="display: inline-block;width:350px">
        R1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK">
      <input id="someID-5" name="nappi" type="radio">
      <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:right;width:0">
        <div id="navi5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="kierros" id="extra" style="display: inline-block;width:70px">
        extra
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="someID-100" name="nappi" type="radio">
    <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:right;width:0">
      <div id="navi100"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;left:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;right:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no child `#extra` of that input. Just remove that from the selector.

```css
input[type="radio"]#someID-1:checked {
  width: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kaaviotaulukko" style="white-space: nowrap; position: relative; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <!--
-->
    <DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-1" />
      <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:left;width:0">
        <div id="navi3">
          <div style="z-index:100;position:fixed;right:0;top:300px"><span><label for="someID-1">1</label></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kierros" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:350px">R1
      </div>
    </DIV>
    <!--
-->
    <DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-5" />
      <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:right;width:0">
        <div id="navi5">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kierros" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:70px" id="extra">extra
      </div>
    </DIV>
    <!--
--><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-100" />
    <div class="listaus-sisalto" style="float:right;width:0">
      <div id="navi100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--

-->
    <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;left:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red"><br />
    </div>

    <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;right:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red"><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div which id is "extra" should be modified. Its width should be 4000px.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `input[type="radio"]#someID-1:checked #extra` selects an element with the id `extra` that is a child element of your radio button. Since radio buttons rarely have children, you'll need to change the selector to match your HTML structure.

I suggest placing the radio button inside the same parent element as `#extra`. That way you can use the selector `input[type="radio"]#someID-1:checked ~ #extra` which will target the `#extra` element if it is preceded by the radio button in selected state.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to keep my HTML structure the same and do the job?

Comment: Unfortunately not without JavaScript. CSS currently has no method to return from a deeper level of nesting and you'd need to go up one level to reach `#extra`.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of what you'd like to become.

```css
#radiodiv {
    background: red;
}

#radio:checked + #radiodiv {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio" type="radio" />

<div id="radiodiv">
<p>This is the div</p>
</div>
```